# ContentDialog.ShowAsync Does Not Respond To Clicks

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, uwp, dialog

I am trying to show a content dialog on my page to ask someone for their name. I'm having a problem where when the dialog pops up, it does not respond to any mouse input. I can tab through the fields and buttons and hit enter, but no mouse input is received. I've searched this quite a bit and nothing really fits my specific problem and I've also tried adding a `Task.Delay(10)` before the `ShowDialog()`.  Here's what I have:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(_currentUser.FirstName == null)
    {
       var result = await ShowDialog();
    }
}
private async Task<ContentDialogResult> ShowDialog()
{
    return await userInfoDialog.ShowAsync().AsTask();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Dialog XAML:

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="userInfoDialog" Title="Enter User Information"
                   PrimaryButtonText="Accept" SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
                   PrimaryButtonClick="userInfoDialog_PrimaryButtonClick">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">
            <TextBox x:Name="userFirstName" PlaceholderText="First Name"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="userLastName" PlaceholderText="Last Name"/>
        </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

Comment: Could you please add your nameDialog

Comment: Sure thing, sorry I didn't include it earlier. I also forgot I renamed the dialog so I updated that.

Comment: What's your project target/min version and OS build version?

Comment: Oh you being up a good point that I haven't thought about. I'm on the insider build of windows. That might do something. I'm targeting minimum as fall creators update.

Comment: So I tried it by myself and I dont have that problem... Maybe there is something in your dode behind of the userInfoDialog that is wrong

Comment: Why do you do "return await userInfoDialog.ShowAsync().AsTask();" you could try "return await userInfoDialog.ShowAsync();" as a I think the former might move it off the UI thread which could explain your issue